# REST extra fields and join in Yii2

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I have this schema in my database.

- time_sheet
- mission
- position
- order

One mission have many timesheets and one time sheet have just one mission.

One position have many missions and one mission have just one position.

One order have many positions and one position have just one order.

And in my class that extends from `yii\rest\IndexAction` I have this code (in the `prepareDataProvider()` method):

```
$query = $timeSheetModel->find()
    ->distinct()
    ->joinWith("mission")
    ->joinWith("mission.position")
    ->joinWith("mission.position.order")
    ->where("public.order.id = $id");

$results = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,    
]);

return $results;
```

So how to personalise my extra fields to get a json with the following structure:

- timeSheet

  - mission
  - position
  - resource
  - order

Answer (score 3):

To return specific fields, in your model for example you could override the fields method:

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        'misson' => function($model) {
            return $model->mission->id; // or anything else from the mission relation
        },
        ... etc.
    ];
}
```

More info about the fields and extraFields methods is available in the yii2 doc - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#fields

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayDataProvider (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html)

```
    $query = new \yii\db\Query();
    $query = $timeSheetModel->find()
        ->distinct()
        ->joinWith("mission")
        ->joinWith("mission.position")
        ->joinWith("mission.position.order")
        ->where("public.order.id = $id");

    $results = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $query->all(),
        // Add pagination information if required
    ]);

    $datas = $results->allModels;

    foreach($datas as &$data) {
        // Do your formatting here 
    }

    $results->allModels = $datas;

    return $results;
```